# Firebase trigger Email extension newlines are not preserved

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I want to use the trigger emails firebase extension. When i format my text with html i get the layout I want, however i am much more likely to be placed in the spam folder.
So I want to send plain text. However, i can not get the newline to stay in the final text. When i send things with the Sendgrid python api `"Hello\r\nWORL!"` will result in the email looking correct

```
Hello
World!
```

however, the firebase extension will send "Hello\r\nWORL!". i tried \n\n, escaping the slashes, (\n), 
, among others.. nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

The firebase extension will watch a specific collection for new documents. Are you perhaps testing this by adding a document through the firebase console UI? I think doing this may escape line breaks automatically.

I just tried this out myself and I could reproduce your issue when adding a document through the firebase console, but the line break was sent correctly when I added a document through the SDK.

I think when adding a text field in the console, firebase will register that you want two distinct characters, '\' and 'n' instead of an end of line character.

Comment: ahhh thank you for the reply!!! yes indeed i was doing it through the firebase console UI, as it was the fastest way for me add document.